# arrange diagram

Tags: diagram

[image]

I made a qt node to draw a diagram. and I want to arrange the diagram. But I can't find the way :( I think that the flow of the diagram solve the my problem. So I want to get the solution of finding the flow. With above figure, I want to get a list like that

```
[A, B]
[A, C, D]
[A, C, E]
```

Each node have a parent and children links, so I can find those. With recursive function, can I find the answer? What algorithm I have to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have here is a graph (from graph theory, not bar-charts and the like). In this case it is tree - but if there was a link from say B to D, then it would not be a tree anymore.

So in order to "find the flow", you should do a "topological sort"; if it's a tree, a "BFS"-run will do, too.

That way you will get the "layers", that is the order from left to right in your diagram and this could be mapped to x coordinates. Finding good y coordinates is easier if the graph is a tree, and more difficult if it is a general graph. In the former case you can determine the locations recursively ("bottom-up") by arranging each node's subtree - i.e. all elements to the right of it.

In case your structure is a graph you could take a look at Sugiyama's algorithm, but this is more involved. I suggest to use a graph library in that case.

The latter algorithm is implemented here to play with:

- go to [Interactive Graph Source Demo](http://live.yworks.com/yfiles-for-html/demos/DataBinding/demo.yfiles.binding.interactivegraphsource/index.html)
- then switch the combobox at the top to "2 Dynamic Bindings"
  and modify the text boxes to the right as follows:

Nodes Source:

```
['A','B','C','D','E']
```

Edges Source:

```
['AB', 'AC', 'CD', 'CE']
```

- Then press the apply button on the top right and you get your graph from above, neatly animated.